# Merge object with React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Say, I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
foo: bar,
foo-one: bar-one,
foo-two: bar-two
}
```

and I have a React state. How can I merge object with state, so object keys will become state keys and object values will become state values apart from standart:

```
this.setState({
   foo: this.obj.foo,
   foo-one: this.obj.bar-one,
   foo-two: this.obj.bar-two
})
```

Comment: What's wrong with `setState()`? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Thomas setState is fine. Thing is, my object is quite large. I wanted to know whether I can write less code without making setState big, as I have about 20 keys in my object

Comment: You know that you only have to set the keys that you actually want to change (in class components). You don't have to pass in the entire state every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that way:

```
setYourObjectInState = () => {
    const objectWithNewValues = {
        foo: bar,
        foo-one: bar-one,
        foo-two: bar-two
    };

    this.setState({
        ...objectWithNewValues
    )};
}
```

EXAMPLES OF SET STATE + SPREAD OBJECTS USAGE:
Or create an object in your function to reproduce your state and then add the keys with values that you want.

```
setYourObjectInState = () => {
    const yourObjectInState = {
        ...this.state.yourObjectInState,
        foo: bar,
        foo-one: bar-one,
        foo-two: bar-two
    };

    this.setState({
        yourObjectInState
    )};
}
```

Or you can simply do like

```
setYourObjectInState = () => {
    const yourNewObject = {
        foo: bar,
        foo-one: bar-one,
        foo-two: bar-two
    };

    this.setState({
        yourObjectInState: {
            ...this.state.yourObjectInState,
            ...yourNewObject
        }
    )};
}
```

or even:

```
setYourObjectInState = () => {
    this.setState({
        yourObjectInState: {
            ...this.state.yourObjectInState,
            foo: bar,
            foo-one: bar-one,
            foo-two: bar-two
        }
    )};
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing `setState`s job? What's wrong with OPs code? It will automatically (flat) merge the current state with the changes passed in. So why do you manually merge the changes with the previous state? And what's the benefit of this extra object?

Comment: I just created an example object to explain, he doesn`t need to create a new one, i will edit with the optional setState creation without a new object (just for readability).